# C++ How to insert in std::multimap?

Tags: c++, dictionary, multimap

How can i insert  in  `std::multimap <bool life, int id, std::pair < x, y >>` ?

I ll use it for storing data's player and ia, Is it the best container for this?

Comment: Have you tried `insert`?

Comment: The third template parameter of `std::multimap` is a comparator. I'm clueless as to what you're trying to do exactly. The explanation in the question and the bit of code you've provided make no sense to me.

Comment: You can find useful documentation on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Answer (score 3):

Not good at all.

The signature of a multimap is as follows:

```
template < class Key,                                   // multimap::key_type
           class T,                                     // multimap::mapped_type
           class Compare = less<Key>,                   // multimap::key_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >  // multimap::allocator_type
           > class multimap;
```

The use of your multimap is wrong.

The **key** is `bool` which means you use only two nodes `0` and `1` (or `false´ and`true`). So each inserted element is in either one of them, and thus you are actually enlisting elements with the same key. This is inefficient.

The **value** is an `int`. Well, alright though I wonder why would you want to map a `bool` to an `int`.

And lastly the error in your signature: `pair` is not a **compare function**, but the third template argument must be a **compare function**. If you leave it empty then by default if would be `less<bool>` (because you chose `bool` as the **key**).